# What is the definition of subcollection in topology?

Tags: general-topology, definition

I had thought that subcollection referred to a collection of sets in some topological space $(X,\tau)$, where each set is a subset of $X$

But I also see it being used in subbasis, and subspace topology so I have gotten a little bit unsure.

What is the proper definition of subcollection and its usage?

Is it collection to say: "Let $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a subcollection of sets in $\tau$"?

Comment: $\tau$ is a collection of sets. A subcollection is simply a collection whose elements are all contained in some supercollection (in this case, that supercollection is $\tau$).

Comment: @neil Oh so the "sub" does not refer to "subset" of $X$

Comment: If you consider a collection simply a set whose elements are sets, a subcollection is a subset of a collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Collection" and "subcollection" are just synonyms of "set" and "subset" that are sometimes used to avoid confusion (particularly when the elements of these sets are themselves sets).  So a collection $A$ of sets is just a set of sets, and then a subcollection of $A$ is just a subset of $A$ (i.e., a set of sets, all of which are elements of $A$).  The term "subcollection" on its own has no meaning; it is always used to refer to a subcollection *of* some particular other collection.